# Geolocation latitude and longitude with javascript as separate variables

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I am trying to store the geolocation values on an array in order to store latitude and longitude as separate variables that can be accessible later during the code.

The idea is to store the array with the variables under the variable `pos`. However I always get an `undefined` value when I console.log it. If I console.log before the return, the values are actually there.

Ideas?

```
function onPositionUpdate(position)
{
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    var latlng = [lat,lng];
    return latlng;
}

var pos = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate);

console.log(pos);
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't return anything. And it's asynchronous.

```
let pos; 
function onPositionUpdate(position) {
    // async action goes second (not undefined)
    const lat = position.coords.latitude;
    const lng = position.coords.longitude;
    pos = [lat,lng];
    console.log(pos);
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate);
// there are no value yet (undefined)
console.log(pos);

const pingPos = setInterval(() => {
    if (pos) {
        clearInterval(pingPos);
        console.log(pos); // not undefined
    }
}, 100);
```

You can use it like this

```
const getPosition = (cb) => {
    const onPositionUpdate = (position) => {
        const lat = position.coords.latitude;
        const lng = position.coords.longitude;
        pos = [lat,lng];

        cb.apply(null, pos)
    }

    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate);
}

// use it anywhere
getPosition((position) => {
    console.log(position);
});
```

Or use async/await or promises

```
const getPosition = () => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const onSuccess = (position) => {
            const lat = position.coords.latitude;
            const lng = position.coords.longitude;
            pos = [lat,lng];

            resolve(pos)
        }

        const onError = () => {
            console.log('Can\'t get location info');
            reject();
        }

        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
    })
}

// use it anywhere
getPosition().then((position) => {
    console.log(position);
});
```

Comment: That still returns the "undefined" value.

Comment: @Alberto See my updated answer, It's similar to ajax request. You can get value only after it was got

Comment: I see your point. But how can I force it to wait until the value is returned? The idea is that I should be able to access "pos" later on the code.

Comment: @Alberto See the example. You can reach it only in the callback. So all your actions should be inside it

Comment: Almost there. Your code works flawless. My issue is that I need to store the values on a variable that needs to be accessible outside any function. It looks like this can't be achieved.

Comment: It can be accessible outside but only after async request will be resolved (see the first code snippet edited in my answer). Before that it will be undefined. 
Your code which uses that variable should be activated after resolve. There is no other options.